# Generalize joint PDF of X and Y to joint PDF X and a vector Y

Tags: statistics

Let there be the independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with a known PDFs $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$. Now, let there be a $k$ length random vector $\vec{Y}$ that is composed of i.i.d. $Y$'s

My question is: How can I write $f_{X, \vec{Y}}$ in a form using $f_{X}$, $f_{Y}$, and $k$?

If it is unclear what I mean by $\vec{Y}$, here is an example...

We could let $Y \sim N(2,15)$ and let $k = 3$. Then $\vec{Y}$ would be $\begin{bmatrix}Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3\end{bmatrix}$ where...

$Y_1 \sim N(2,15)$

$Y_2 \sim N(2,15)$

$Y_3 \sim N(2,15)$

---

EDIT:
I think I solved it. 
Since X and Y are independent, then...

$$f_{X, \vec{Y}}(x, \vec{y}) = f_X(x) * \prod_{i = 1}^{k} f_Y(\vec{y}_i)$$

Is this right?

Comment: What does "i.i.d. $Y$s" mean with regard to the dependence on $X$?

Comment: I was trying to say that all elements of $\vec{Y}$ are independent of each other and all distributed like Y - including any covariance with X.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I think your attempt is correct.